# Mac OSX: Get 'make' to use 'gcc' instead of 'arm-gcc'

Tags: macos, gcc, command-line, arm

I had installed arm toolchain to build some projects. The issue is, that during my installation I had modified the 'make' from the command line tools to use the arm-gcc compiler instead of gcc.

I now want it to use gcc again. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Where exactly is the place where make is defined on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always overwrite it in the Makefile of the project you are building:

```
CC=gcc
```

you may need the fully qualified name.

Comment: yeah, I guess thats the way to go unfortunately, I shouldn't have installed using 'sudo' unfortunately, and I can't seem to find the bash script I used anymore... :(

Comment: You can also try to modify /etc/make.conf...that sets the default system-wide options for make.